# What's the microscopic driven force of heating?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces

Consider an isolated box which contains a gas of noble molecules.If we put the box on the fire and after a little time, the temperature of the box will increase due to these molecules are heated and hence will move more quickly.

> So my question is how that happens? I mean what's driven force to accelerate these molecules? What's the microscopic process of heating?I mean is there any boson (such as phonon) exchange just like the electrical force driven by exchange photon?

Answer (score 3):

**CONDUCTION**

It's simple. The flame conducts heat to the box. The box gets excited with its atoms and molecules vibrating and clashing with each other. This in turn bumps into the gas molecules inside the box and the same thing happens again. It's just a process of conduction. It's like having a box full of candy and children sitting in a circle, then each child would take a candy and pass the box along.

Comment: Can you tell me more about flame?How does it transfer the energy?

Comment: So basically fuel like gasoline or wood have chemical bonds which has a certain amount of stored energy. Through the process of combustion, these molecules react with oxygen and they release the energy stored. This energy is in the form of heat.